# TortoiseGit diff hangs

Tags: tortoisegit

I have the weirdest problem. When I run TortoiseGit diff on one particular file the diff tool just freezes. My coworkers do not have the same problem so it has to be a local problem. I can view the other files in the repository without problem.

Have anyone else ever experienced anything similar?

Comment: Please give a reason if you downwote my question! This is a real problem.

Comment: How do you run TortoiseGit diff? TortoiseGitMerge? TortoiseGitUDiff? TortoiseGitIDiff? (Oh~ I am not the downvote person. But, I think you didn't provide enough information.)

Comment: Thankyou for answering Yue Lin Ho. I either right click on the file and choose "tortoise git"->diff or double click on the file from the log. The tool that opens and hangs is tortoiseGitMerge.

Comment: Is that particular file huge? What happened if (1) Right click on that file and Show log, (2) Right click on that file and Show changes as unified diff?

Comment: the file is 2200lines which I would say is large, but I have other files that I can diff that are more that twice as large.
Unified diff works..

Comment: Could you please follow the section "Capture Debug Strings" of [this doc](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/master/src/Debug-Hints.txt)?

Comment: Please report bugs to https://tortoisegit.org/issues

Comment: I activated debug strings and captured almost 100 error strings. But it seems like there are a lot of duplicates, there are only 3 unique error strings

Comment: [7032] shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFAB2938D28: (caller: 00007FFAC9CECCA0) ReturnHr[PreRelease](276) tid(31e4) 80030002 %1 could not be found.

Comment: [7032] shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFAB29432DC: (caller: 00007FFAB29434FF) ReturnHr[PreRelease](277) tid(1db4) 8004B203

Comment: [7032] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(1144)\explorerframe.dll!00007FFAB402186D: (caller: 00007FFAB403DFC2) ReturnHr[PreRelease](30) tid(31e4) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me either and also once finished long processing it show partial diff, not all the file lines and because of that if differences are below stripped lines they are not shown and you think file has no diffs which is not correct at all if you review lines count with a another file viewer.

Sorry for me english I am not a native english speaker.

Hope this helps.